# Regex: \b for strings that don't start with a word character?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
Lorem #test ^%#test ipsum#test dolor #test sit #testamet.
      ^^^^^                          ^^^^^
```

What regular expression do I use to select only the marked `#test` instances? So if it's part of another word or if it has other characters in it I don't want to select it.

If I were to search for just `test` I would use `/\btest\b/g`, but `\b` does only seem to work if the text is starting with a word character?

Comment: Test whether it is preceded or followed by a white-space character (and the beginning or end or the string).

Comment: Should it match `foo,#test,bar`?

Comment: @Hendrik: I mean, should it match `#test` in this string: `foo,#test,bar`

Comment: @Jerry: I think you went a bit overboard with your edit :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker using the `{}` format doesn't allow bold, so I used the `^` to denote the parts supposed to be bold. Otherwise, leaving it as normal string is a bit hard to read :( Oh right, forgot to change that bit mentioning bold.

Comment: @thg435 Ah sorry, my original thought was no. But actually I would like it to match if it's surrounded by whitespace, comma's or dots. So yes it should match, but I only want to grab the #test part if that's even possible.

Comment: @Hendrik Do you know about group catches? Taking Tim's regex, it'd become `(?:^|\W)(#test)\b` (notice the brackets).

Comment: @Jerry I know a bit about them, but I understand the solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact substitute for `\b` because JavaScript doesn't have [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

But if you don't mind that a preceding space character becomes part of the match, you can use

```
/(?:^|\s)#test\b/m
```

This matches `"#test"` if it's at the beginning of a line or `" #test"` if it's not.

If you want other characters than spaces to delimit your "word boundary", then you can specify them. For example, if you want to accept anything but a `\w` character, then use

```
/(?:^|\W)#test\b/m
```

which will match `",#test"` in `"foo,#test,foo"`. You can't get rid of the comma in the match, unfortunately. But if you use

```
var match = /(?:^|\W)(#test)\b/m.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

you're at least close.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps!